# Creating entity dependencies using IDependableEntityDefinition in Cofoundry

Tags: c#, dependencies, cofoundry

Are there any examples of using the `IDependableEntityDefinition` and how to link two custom entities that implement `ICustomEntityDataModel`?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably only use `IDependableEntityDefinition` if you were linking from a custom entity out to a non-cofoundry entity, so it's a bit of an advanced use-case and isn't documented.

If you want to link between custom entities you should use the custom entity data annotations such as `[CustomEntity]`, `[CustomEntityCollection]` or `[CustomEntityMultiTypeCollection]`, there's some descriptions of these attributes in the [docs](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/content-management/data-model-annotations). These attributes will automatically track dependencies for you, and prevent deletions on dependent entities if the relationship is not optional.

In the example below, the `BreedId` is a required dependency, and the `FurPatternId` is optional:

```cs
public class CatDataModel : ICustomEntityDataModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [CustomEntity(BreedCustomEntityDefinition.DefinitionCode)]
    public int BreedId { get; set; }

    [CustomEntity(FurPatternCustomEntityDefinition.DefinitionCode)]
    public int? FurPatternId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, I really appreciate it.

The original cause of the question was we have a scenario where we are able to publish a custom entity that has a nested custom entity that is unpublished. Is there a way to prevent this scenario so that nested entities must be published for the parent to be published? (apologies if asking a subsequent question is bad practice, I'm new to stack overflow) 

Thanks again, 
G

Comment: @Gareth there's no facility to validate they are published (relations could become unpublished at a later date). We expect this to be taken care of when querying related entiries, see [entity versioning](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/content-management/entity-versioning) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks and will do. Have a good December!